# How to use multi-level parallelization in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The scenario:
Main process reads some configuration file and spawns off 3 processes - A, B and C. Each of these children read their own configuration files and spawns of multiple processes - A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5. (Process A spawns Ax, etc.).

Now, process A needs to wait for A1, A2 and A3, and then do some work; process B needs to wait for B1 and B2, and so on. The main process needs to wait for all 3 processes (A, B and C) to be completed, and finalize some other tasks.

What is the recommended way to do this? Essentially, this is a  "spawn a few children, let them run in parallel and wait for all of them to complete" problem in multiple levels.

I have tried multiprocessing, but it applies only to **main**

I have tried os.fork(), but cannot get the child process to exit.
sys.exit(n) or os._exit(n) creates zombie processes and the parent
cannot detect when a child has exited (how does one exit)?

Thank you for a hint.

```
def level2 (letterWithNumber):
    # do something with letter and number
    sys.exit(0)

def level1 (letter, conFileName):
    plist = anotherListFromConfigFile(conFileName)   # returns [A1, A2, A3] for A, etc.
    bList = array('i', [])
    bCount = 0
    foreach key in plist:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            level2 (key)
        else:
            bList.append(pid)
            bCount += 1

    while True:
        count = 0
        for p in blist
            if waitpid(p,0):    # child is active
                count += 1
        if count == 0:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(10)
    print (bCount, "jobs completed for task", letter
    sys.exit(0)

# main

dict = listFromConfigFile() # contains {A: a.conf, B: b.conf, C: c.conf}
alist = array('i', [])
ccount = 0
foreach key in dict:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        level1(key, dict[key])
    else:
        alist.append(pid)
        ccount += 1

while True:
    count = 0
    for p in alist
        if waitpid(p,0):    # child is active
            count += 1
    if count == 0:
        break
    else
        time.sleep(10)

print (ccount, "top level tasks completed")
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you please add some code and explain your question a little more? Thanks!

Comment: I think that you need to put examples of your code what you try to do. Because can convert this question in a discussion in what  everybody get their point of view and that's not the idea of stackoverflow is more for sites like https://www.quora.com/. On other hand the examples that the people can give you if you put you code can be focus in your real problem and can criticism your code.

Comment: Here is a pseudocode of what I am trying to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I have completely got your point. But if you just want your process to wait other processes, you could use `process.join()`

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def time_consume():
    import time
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

process = Process(target=time_consume)
process.start()
process.join()
print("process finished.")
```

So actually, your question is not as complex as you think, at least in my opinion.

You can create three level 1 processes in main process and `join()`, and in every level 1 process, you can also create three level 2 processes, then call `join()` in each level 1 process to wait level 2 processes.

It may like the following:

```
def level_two():
    #do_something

def level_one():
    level_two_processes = [Process(target=level_two), Process(target=level_two)]
    for process in level_two_processes:
        process.start()
    #do_something
    for process in level_two_processes:
        process.join()

def main():
    level_one_processes = [Process(target=level_one), Process(target=level_one)]
    for process in level_one_processes:
        process.start()
    #do_something
    for process in level_one_processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for - will implement this. Thank you, once again.